# Poor rendering: is my computer about to die?

Tags: macos, mac, hardware-failure

Recently, my computer has begun to render some websites really poorly. Example:

[image: Screenshot of crappy rendering in Firefox]

This mostly happens in Firefox, but sometimes also in Chrome; it can usually be fixed by updating the page. However, I am wondering if it's a sign that my computer is getting closer to death. (I don't know if a computer can be in any other states than 'alive' and 'dead' and what results that would produce). It happens even when almost no other programs are open.

Any ideas what could be causing this problem? Details:

- MacBook4,1, 2008
- Core 2 Duo 2.4GHz, 4GB RAM
- Graphics: Intel GMA X3100, 144 MB VRAM
- OS X 10.6.7
- Firefox 3.6.16

Cheers!

Comment: Seems to me that if it shows up in a screenshot (and you have dedicated video RAM) it has to be an issue with the graphics card. I'll leave it to someone more knowledgeable to post an answer, though it might be worth checking temperatures (I don't know of a good OS X utility offhand).

Comment: Perhaps it's a belated April Fools joke?

Comment: @Mehrdad, no April Fools ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it might have something to do with your graphics card.
Of course I don't have a Mac, but the problem you are describing would seem to be an issue with your graphics card.
I don't think it has anything to do with the age of your computer; I am running a 2004 Windows XP with a single-core processor and 2Gb of RAM (after I quadrupled it) and it's running just fine (I also have a Windows 95 from 1996 that runs perfectly-actually faster than some brand new computers I have seen)